# window-based file manager resistant to network drivers lost connection

Tags: ubuntu, file-manager, nas

I have ubuntu, and I have mounted NAS on my computer. NAS can be mounted only if VPN is active. The problem is, when a connection problem occures, or when I umount the NAS resources, the file manager hangs for minutes. I have tried a few file managers, but the problem is still present. Some of my bookmarks in file manager points to subtree in NAS resources. Is there any ubuntu file manager resistant to this problem? File manager shouldn't hangs during network problems.

Comment: What behaviour are you hoping for?

Comment: No hanging file manager - ignoring remote folders of NAS

Comment: Make amendments by editing the question.